# How to isolate values in a dataframe based on a vector and multiply it by another column in the same dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, col

I have a dataframe with multiple columns

```
col1|col2|col3|colA|colB|colC|Percent
  1     1    1    2    2    2     50
```

Earlier I subset the columns and created a vector

```
ColAlphabet<-c("ColA","ColB","ColC")
```

What i want to do is take ColAlphabet and multiply it by Percent so in the end I have

```
col1|col2|col3|colA|colB|colC|Percent
  1    1    1     1    1    1      50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`.  Specify the columns of interest wrapped with `all_of` and multiply the columns with 'Percent'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(across(all_of(ColAlphabet), ~ .* Percent/100))
```

-output

```
df2
#  col1 col2 col3 colA colB colC Percent
#1    1    1    1    1    1    1      50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = 1L, col2 = 1L, col3 = 1L, colA = 2L, colB = 2L, 
    colC = 2L, Percent = 50L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Do you know why I get Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , vector, value = list(col1 = list( :
  provided 22 variables to replace 21 variables

Comment: @user35131 Is it on the same example in my post or a different one as I am not getting any warnings

Comment: Warning message: In [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, , vector, value = list(col1 = list( : provided 22 variables to replace 21 variables

Comment: @user35131 Is it possible to get the `dput(yourdataset)` if it is 1 row dataset so that I get the structure of the data to understasnd the issue

Comment: @user35131 if the structure is same as in your previous post, you may have to `unlist` because the column is a list column i.e. `df1 %>%
     mutate(across(all_of(ColAlphabet), ~ unlist(.)* Percent/100))`

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 3211.
i Input `..1` is `across(all_of(ColAlphabet), ~unlist(.) * Percent)`.
i Input `..1` must be size 3211 or 1, not 538297.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: There were 42 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: it does math on 21 out of 22 values.

Comment: its too long to fit here.

Comment: @user35131 is it possible that all the columns in the ColAlphabet are present in the dataset

Comment: @user35131 can you post a dput or small data in github and give the link

Comment: Yes it looks like it is.

Comment: @user35131 please post the link.  I will look into it. thanks

Comment: I have a geometry column at the end that I don't want a part of this.This might be causing the the issue.

Comment: @user35131 that could be the reason.  You could remove that element from `ColAlphabet` and then run it again

Comment: Its not in ColAlphabet but its the last the column in the dataframe. So when I do df[ColAlphabet] it'll show up. I'm thinking if i remove it temporarily in the formula and have it not included it should work.

Comment: @user35131 It could be that the `geometry` attribute have some clash with the `across` option.  Can you try  with `mutate_at` instead i.e. `df1 %>%
     mutate_at(vars(ColAlphabet), ~ .* Percent/100)`

Comment: It worked but what I find strange is I have to run it twice.

Comment: @user35131 the geometry data attribute is a bit complex.  I would subset the data by selecting columns except those and then bind it later

Comment: Good idea! Thanks for your help. I can conclude this.

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the column, multiply with `Percent` and save it in `ColAlphabet` again.

```
ColAlphabet<-c("colA","colB","colC")
df[ColAlphabet] <- df[ColAlphabet] * df$Percent/100
df

#  col1 col2 col3 colA colB colC Percent
#1    1    1    1    1    1    1      50
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `apply()`:

```
#Vector
ColAlphabet<-c("colA","colB","colC")
#Code
df[,ColAlphabet] <- apply(df[,ColAlphabet],2,function(x) x*df$Percent/100)
```

Output:

```
df
  col1 col2 col3 colA colB colC Percent
1    1    1    1    1    1    1      50
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(col1 = 1L, col2 = 1L, col3 = 1L, colA = 2L, colB = 2L, 
    colC = 2L, Percent = 50L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to multiply directly:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = 1, colA = 2, colB = 2, colC = 2, Percent = 50)
> df
  col1 col2 col3 colA colB colC Percent
1    1    1    1    2    2    2      50
> df[grep('^c.*[A-Z]$', names(df))] <- df[grep('^c.*[A-Z]$', names(df))] * df$Percent/100
> df
  col1 col2 col3 colA colB colC Percent
1    1    1    1    1    1    1      50
>
```